# Is CInternetSession secure? Is it being encrypted?

Tags: c++, http, post, encryption

I make an `HTTP POST` request to a SharePoint website which requires the user's `credential`.

I want to make sure that the `username` and `password` that are being used are secure and cannot be easily sniffed.

I have looked around to see if `CInternetSession` encrypts the data but I haven't found any reliable information.

**Is it secure for me to use this code?**

I am passing these credential as following:

```
void CUserPassDiag::Connect(){

CString username;
CString password;
m_UsernameCEditControl.GetWindowText(username); // get username
m_passwordCEditControl.GetWindowText(password); // get password

CInternetSession session(_T("session"));
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
const int szBuffSize = 20000; 
char *szBuff = new char[szBuffSize]; // needed to store the html file

try
{
    /*
     * First Request - Retrieve the HTML page
     */

    CString strServerName = _T("SPsite");

    // Physyical Location Widget URL
    CString strObject = _T("/somepage.aspx");

    // Headers for the POST Request
    CString headers = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    headers += _T("Host: SPsite\r\n");
    headers += _T("Pragma: no-cache\r\n");
    headers += _T("Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, *//*\r\n");
    headers += _T("Accept-Language: en-CA\r\n");\
    headers += _T("Referer: SPsite/somepage.aspx\r\n");

    // Headers Ready
    CString szHeaders = _T(headers);

    // This will store the POST request return value
    DWORD dwRet;

    // Get connection with username and password
    pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, _T(username), _T(password));

    // open request
    pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, strObject);
    pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);
    pFile->SendRequest();
    }catch(){
     }
  }
```

Comment: Use SSL to make life easy. Does your website support the `https://`?

Comment: not `https`, it's `http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetHttpConnection` just calls WinAPI's `InternetConnect` from WinInet library. It is not secure unless it goes through secure port with `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT` option for "https://" URLs.

Lets say the password is "blue-cheese". If I tell you the password then everybody else will see it. I could encrypt the password with another password, then I have to tell you the other password, everybody else will see that too. So there is no way I can send you a password over open channel, unless using methods like Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

If the program is for yourself only, or you can protect its method, then you can make a response challenge systems between your software and your website.

If you are making a program for public release then basically this is not possible without SSL, because hackers can monitor what your code does.